# Automatically create "static const R_CMethodDef CEntries[]" for R package with .c files?

Tags: r

I built my own package which include `.c` files. This is the first time I build my own package and with `.c`. I read through some packges that already have `.c` files and I find this folder `int.c`. I see inside the folder the name of `.c` files. I just wonder do I need to that manually. That is do I need to do "static const R_CMethodDef CEntries[]" and the registreation of the `.c` files manually or not? Or can I do it automatically calling some command?

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see the NEWS file for R 3.4.0, or, the following posts from my blog detailing different ways:

- [first: "easy"](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/03/29#001_easy_package_registration)
- [second: "even easier"](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/03/30#002_even_easier_package_registration)
- [third: "easiest"](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/04/30#006_easiest_package_registration)

These days you can just rely on the last post.

And, of course, if you use Rcpp it also done *automagically* for you when the glue code is inserted as part of `compileAttributes()`.

Comment: I would like to use Rcpp but I see using `.Call` do not allowed me to use my own wraper R function. It is done automaticlaly. And I think Rcpp only work for `.c++` files, and only with `.Call` is that correct or I am worng?

Comment: Please edit the question. It is not customary in North America to yell at people by their family name. I am also not your personal tutor -- Rcpp help is available the `rcpp-devel` mailing list.   As for the rest if your question, it is plain wrong.  You could write (essentially) plain C code in cpp file and still have Rcpp do all its work for you,

Comment: Sorry but I am not yell you at your family name I use `@` to call all your name as it is appear in your file but I see only the second name is apper in my comment. then I go to your file to copy your full name. I was a unwanted mistake. Yes you are not my personal tutor if you like to help or not it is up to  you. Sorry. Your answer is very helpful but if  you like to delete it is OK. Sorry agian but please ask the people why they did some thing before be angry with them, may you misunderstand them, may be it an accedent mistake.